# What does 'given rate' mean?

Tags: air-traffic-control, terminology, phraseology

I was watching this video:

[At around 1:28](https://youtu.be/97UarwKILzI?t=88) I heard the controller clear a plane to descend to a level "given rate". I was searching online but couldn't seem to find what they meant with the term 'given rate'.

Could it be the "level change" or "open descend" button in the aircraft?

Comment: Sometimes, a controller will give you a specific rate of descent along with descent clearance. Example: "Descend FL140, rate 1500 feet per minute or more". When a new descent clearance is given, "given rate" indicates that the previous rate of descent restriction still applies. In this example, if a subsequence clearance was given: "Descend FL80, given rate" it would mean the same as "Descend FL80, rate 1500 feet per minute".

Comment: Appreciated! Got any source on this? (It makes sense but still) :)

Comment: I'm actually not sure whether it is really standard phraseology. You could always check out CAP 413.

Answer (score 2):

The ARTCC Controller is telling a flight crew currently descending to descend to FL150 at their current rate of descent e.g. 2000 fpm, etc. either to expedite their current descent or the controller is satisfied with the current rate of descent to traffic separation and flow into the terminal area where the flight will be landing.

Comment: ARTCC is a FAA local terminology, Europe uses the ICAO wording ACC (area control center). Here probably [Langen ACC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Flugsicherung#Area_control_centers) (EDGG) in Langen FIR.

Comment: Got any source on this? Thanks!

Comment: If the controller wanted the "Current Rate"  think he would have said so.  
        I have flown into Frankfurt many times and have never heard the phrase "Given Rate" used. It may have been a short term phraseology trial, but it also makes sense to me that the pilot may have been told earlier to descend at specific rate of descent and that the controller was again asking to descend at the same "given rate".

Comment: It might not be perfect phraseology, but that’s what the controller meant.

Answer (score 0):

'Given rate' is non-standard phraseology. The 'given rate' refers to a 'rate of descent' given in a previous instruction.

Comment: Hello and welcome to aviation.se. While your answer may be correct it is very short and of rather poor quality. It would be greatly appreciated if you could provide some background information and ressources to your post.